# How to get all records with the same INNER JOIN'ed ID

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables:

- `products_tb` - holds set brief information about a certain product which isn't going to change
- marketplace_tb - holds all records of listings, linking to the products_tb on `Product_ID`

I have a query where I am trying to get all records of data where the marketplace is a certain country (GB / US etc.) and the category is the type of product (Book, Laptop etc.)

It works, however as I am inner joining two tables based on a certain ID (`Product_ID`) it's only outputting 1 record per individual `product_id`, is there a way to get it to output all records of data regardless if its got the same product listing? (as the same product could be listed multiple times under different prices for examples)

Thanks for your help guys.

```
SELECT * FROM products_tb as a
INNER JOIN marketplace_tb as b ON a.Product_ID = b.Product_ID
WHERE Product_Category_p = '$category'
AND b.Country_Name_m = '$country'
```

Comment: This should output all matching records.

Comment: @Barmar It only outputs all matching records where the Product_ID it links to is different.

Comment: It works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a87zFv98crPte2DTW6M2s/0 Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @BobK "It only outputs all matching records where the Product_ID it links to is different" That statement doesn't make sense. I agree with Barmar that your query does actually do what you appear to want. If you have, say, 5 records in `marketplace_tb` whose product ID links to products of category Book and whose country matches your filter, then you will get 5 rows back which is simply the row from `products_tb`and the row from `marketplace_tb` stuck together. Your question is unclear but as Barmar suggests, the addition of some simple test data and the expected result would help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the query was correct. The method for inputting the Product_IDs was incorrect and it was inputting the same ID (8, which was the last row) regardless of which product i chose which meant the right product didnt show up under the category.

Thanks a lot for your great help.